# opening jupyter notebook on remote computer using mobaxterm

Tags: ssh, openssh, jupyter-notebook, mobaxterm

I am trying to open jupyter notebook on my laptop by accessing my server through mobaxterm.

when I type `jupyter notebook` into the mobaxterm terminal jupyter notebook opens on my server computer. I have tried `jupyter notebook --no-browser` then trying to paste the http into the address bar of chrome but it says `localhost didnt send any data`. This doesnt change if I set the port as well when i put `jupyter notebook --no-browser --port 8888`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up SSH tunnel for your remote server in order to access Jupyter notebooks on local machine.

Run the below command on the client machine:
plink -ssh -L 8080:localhost:8888 username@server_address

login to the server and start an jupyter notebook instance. you can now access the notebook from this link: http://localhost:8080